# Regex to allow only lowercase characters and numbers

Tags: regex

The code uses the following regExp `^[a-z0-9]+$` to allow only lowercase letters and numbers to validate user input.

But still considers aBcd the valid value, can you please give some insights on what can be the issue here?

Comment: regex compiled with flag "ignore case", very likely.

Comment: Are you maybe using the `i` "case-insensitive" flag?

Comment: If you share us what programming language or tool you are using the regex in, that would be nice.  That way someone who knows it could answer how to let the regex search case-sensitive.

Comment: Is it Powershell? Use `-cmatch`. Is it JS? Remove `i` in `/i` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you compile that regex with a flag "ignore case" or something similar? Or is the regex actually this one?

```
(?i)^[a-z0-9]+$
^^^^
```

If so, you should remove the "case insensitivity" flag so the regex respects capitalization.